# ASP.Net core correct way of implementing http methods for related models

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have tow models *Context* and *Connection* as following:

```
public class Context
{
    [Key]
    public long ContextId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Role { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Connection> Connections { get; set; }

    public Context()
    {

    }
}
```

And

```
public class Connection
{
    [Key]
    public long ConnectionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public long ContextId { get; set; }
    public Context Context { get; set; }

    public Connection()
    {

    }
}
```

So far, I did not create any controller or repository for Connection. ContextRepositiry looks like following:

```
public class ContextRepository: IContextRepository
{
    private readonly WebAPIDataContext _db;

    public ContextRepository(WebAPIDataContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public Context CreateContext(Context context)
    {
        _db.Contexts.Add(context);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return context;
    }

    public void DeleteContext(long id)
    {
        Context context = GetContext(id);
        if (context != null)
        {
            _db.Contexts.Remove(context);
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public List<Context> GetAllContexts()
    {
        return _db.Contexts.AsNoTracking().ToList();
    }

    public Context GetContext(long id)
    {
        return _db.Contexts.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ContextId == id);
    }

    public void UpdateContext(long id, Context context)
    {


    }
}

public interface IContextRepository
{
    List<Context> GetAllContexts();
    Context GetContext(long id);
    Context CreateContext(Context context);
    void UpdateContext(long id, Context context);
    void DeleteContext(long id);
}
```

And it's controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ContextController : Controller
{
    private readonly IContextRepository _contexts;
    public ContextController(IContextRepository contexts)
    {
        _contexts = contexts;
    }

    [HttpGet("")]
    public IActionResult GetAllContexts()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Context> contexts = _contexts.GetAllContexts();
            return Ok(contexts);
        }
        catch (EntityNotFoundException<Context>)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetContext(long id)
    {
        Context context= _contexts.GetContext(id);
        if (context == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(context);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateContext([FromBody] Context context)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        Context createdContext= _contexts.CreateContext(context);
        if (createdContext== null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return CreatedAtAction(
             nameof(GetContext), new { id = createdContext.ContextId}, createdContext);

    }

    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult UpdateContext(long id, [FromBody] Context context)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        try
        {
            _contexts.UpdateContext(id, context);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (EntityNotFoundException<Context>)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public IActionResult DeleteCOntext(long id)
    {
        _contexts.DeleteContext(id);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

**Question**: While creating a *context* I shouldn't have to enter any *connection* data i.e. it should be optional (*look ta the swagger request bellow*). However, on updating a specific context there could be connection data, and corresponding context should be updated accordingly.

Right now, in Swagger for POST if I enter something like:

```
{
  "contextId": 0,
  "role": "Employee",
  "connections": [
    {
      "connectionId": 0,
      "name": "",
      "contextId": 0,
      "context": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

then it says, `The Name field is required` and `The Role field is required` (I am trying to send just context data like role and leaving blank connection data- which should be possible). If I remove `"connections":[]` then it posts with connections set to null, but don't want to remove it from there.

Comment: Right now this post is far too large. Please pick a question and stick to it.

Comment: Okay! I will update my question